# How to collect Date of birth from php form and insert into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date

I am new to programming, have done a few things but i have no idea how to collect dob information.  How do i collect it from a form and how do i insert it? Do i use three fields: month/day/year and then in the db also have three columns?

Is there a tutorial i can be pointed to?

Thanks

Comment: 1 field type = Date http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you're going to do with the data (if it's not going to be too complex), you could simply reformat the submitted form:

```
$bday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['userSubmittedBDay']));
```

and insert that into the database as a string. The above example would give you the format 2011-01-26

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is a cheeky response, but with a [little Google-ing this answer can be found rather easily](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

1. Create a form
2. Collect data from that form
3. Sanitize that input
4. Insert into database

Comment: Sorry to be cheeky as well, i was looking for dob specific php tutorial.

Comment: If you visit that page, there are several tutorials based on MySQL:

PHP Database
MySQL Introduction
MySQL Connect
MySQL Create
MySQL Insert
MySQL Select
MySQL Where
MySQL Order By
MySQL Update
MySQL Delete
PHP ODBC