# query does not save date properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Mysql query is not saving the date of birth as expected but only saving it as 0000-00-00 from a php registration form, what might be the matter?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['registration']))
{
    require "connection.php";
    $FirstName = strip_tags($_POST['FirstName']);
    $LastName = strip_tags($_POST['LastName']);
    $Phone = $_POST['Phone'];

    $Month = $_POST['month'];
    $Day = $_POST['day'];
    $Year = $_POST['year'];

    $Date = $Year."-".$Month."-".$Day;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (FirstName,LastName,Phone,DOB)
            VALUES ( '" . $FirstName . "','". $LastName . "',
            '" . $Phone . "','" . $Year . "-" . $Month . "-" . $Day . "')")
            or  die("".mysql_error());
    echo "Successful Registration!";
}
?>
```

Comment: show us ur registration form's html code.

Comment: add `print $Date; exit;` just before the `mysql_query` and update your question with the output.

Comment: @Sonali well OP is same but as you marked duplicate but your shared link did not provided solution to OP so its not a duplicate...

Comment: @MultiThreader see this question for HTML http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652799/date-not-saving-in-mysql-from-php-registration-form/18652873?noredirect=1#comment27467497_18652873

Comment: an all caps title, seriously?

Comment: @Sonali, can't possibly ask a question that had been resolved before, unfortunately it wasn't resolved. Thanks

Comment: @Sonali well but that was the wrong flag...do not worry moderator will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change below code,

**Replace**

```
$Month = $_POST['month'];
$Day = $_POST['day'];
$Year = $_POST['year'];
```

**with**

```
$Month = $_POST['Birthday_Month'];
$Day = $_POST['Birthday_day'];
$Year = $_POST['Birthday_Year'];
```

because your html you have shared previously is using field name as per `Birthday_Year` and so on.

Comment: I think you have a point but no luck still.. Thank You all the same

Comment: @KnightSlayer now correct date insert code which i mentioned in my previous answer...

Comment: have done that too and it unfortunately it doesn't echo anything.

Comment: can you please share your entire code in zip file on 4shared or anywhere else so i can see it....do not forget to add database table in zip file.

Comment: can do that... kindly send me your email account to petermuya@connectmedia.co.ke.. I forwars you the same, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

**Attach this**

```
 $Date= date('Y-m-d',strtotime($Date));
```

**after**

```
$Date =$Day ."-".$Month."-".$Year; //note some changes
```

Credited to [How to collect Date of birth from php form and insert into mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812194/how-to-collect-date-of-birth-from-php-form-and-insert-into-mysql)

***Be happy :)***

Comment: Hi, have done so it echoes "SUCCESSFUL REGISTRATION" but the date is still being saved as 0000-00-00, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

try to convert string to date then perform query

```
$date = $Year . "-" . $Month . "-" . $Day;
$dob = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
$query="insert into users set FirstName='".$FirstName."',LastName='".$LastName
        ."',Phone='".$Phone."',DOB='".$dob."'";
mysql_query($query)or  die("".mysql_error());
```

Comment: OOOh Rajeev, Thank You I think Your suggested solution just worked in some crazy way, it has saved 1970-01-10

Comment: Don't know if there is a solution to fixing it, as had input oct-5-1980

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"INSERT INTO users (FirstName,LastName,Phone,DOB) VALUES ( '" . $FirstName . "',' at line 1

Comment: The above error popped up... Thank You all the same..

Comment: have tried that too but all is being saved is 1970-01-01 no matter the date being input, Thank You!

Comment: @KnightSlayer please see here supported date format http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php